# Dell touchpad replaced - not working in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, mouse, dell, touchpad, synaptics

Dell Precision 5550. Ubuntu 22.04

Recently replaced the keyboard + touchpad since the keyboard was broken. Ever since the touchpad doesn't work anymore in Ubuntu.

It looks to be a software / driver issue, since the touchpad does work in the BIOS and in Windows (dualboot).

`cat /proc/bus/input/devices` doesn't output anything related to a touchpad.